Apollo Third Stage SLA Separation design change?
Did NASA change the design of the SLA on the Apollo third stage? First leaving it connected and then having the panels separate from the third stage?

Can you be more descriptive about what you're asking?

Can you be more descriptive of what you're asking

What rockets had hinged SLA petals and what rockets had petals that separated away?

Up through Apollo 7, the third stage used a hinged-panel design where the panels would stay attached to the upper stage.  However, during Apollo 7, one of the panels didn't open fully.  In response, the design was changed to one that would jettison the panels instead:

One of the SLA panels did not fully deploy, but this did not cause any problems. On future Saturn vehicles, the SLA panels will be jettisoned.

Since the Apollo 7 crew's first reaction to seeing the SLA panels was to comment about angry alligators, presumably memories of the failure of Gemini 9 played a role in the decision.
